# How to find the row of tableItem?

Tags: java, jface

I created tableviewer ( jface )

In my logic I have TableItem and I need to find the row of the tableItem in the tableViewer.

How I can do it ?

Comment: So where is your code?

Comment: If you explain what you are really trying to do there is probably a better way to do it that this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TableViewer.getTable()` to get the `Table` and then use `Table.indexOf(tableItem)` to get the index.